# How to do the shortcut `Alt + =` typing the identity char ≡?

Tags: linux, hotkeys, xbindkeys

I want to do the shortcut `Alt + =` which puts the identity char ≡.
How to do it with Xbindkeys? Or you need a different method?

Comment: You can find tutorials for assigning xbindkeys to a command - think about using `xdotool` to inject the character you want. You should only have to install xbindkeys, xdotool, and add the key to xbindkeys.rc in your home folder

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/4023/693277) maybe. I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 0):

Install `xdotool` and `xbindkeys`.

Add in `.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xdotool type ≡"
    m:0x90 + c:21
    Mod2+Mod5 + equal
```

But it requires pressing = twice. And it will not always work.

Comment: You might also want to start xbindkeys with startup - simply add the command `xbindkeys` to rc.local or however you want to start. Simply adding it to Session and Startup worked for me on Xfce.

Comment: @QuickishFM I do this.
This solution works badly. More often than not, he does not enter anything. I have to do it differently.

Comment: You mean the solution at hand, or starting `xbindkeys` at startup? I couldn't get the alt + equal binding to work (other bindings work fine though), and `xdotool type ≡` worked just fine for me. As for startup, running xbindkeys in "session and startup" works fine, but AFAIK its only for Xfce.